# Existe um método para remover uma substring de uma string?

Tags: javascript

Por enquanto eu utilizo o método replace pra isso mas queria saber se existe um método que exclusivo pra fazer isso:

```
pontos = `${parseInt(pontos) + aposta}${pontos.replace(parseInt(pontos), "")}`;
```

Comment: O que exatamente precisa fazer? E por quê o método `replace` não atende suas necessidades? Você quer fazer um *replace* e julga que o método `replace` não é o que precisa? Então não está nenhum um pouco claro o que você quer.

Comment: eu quero só remover uma substring de dentro de outra e o replace funciona mas não sei se é o melhor.

Comment: É o melhor. Ele foi criado para isso.

Comment: a função [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) não te ajuda nisso ? @MoraisVilson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe, mas você pode fazer um. Basta adicionar ao protótipo do tipo `String` que todas as strings, tanto já existentes quanto as que ainda serão instanciadas, o terão.

```
String.prototype.remover = function (input) {   
    var output = this;
    while (output.indexOf(input) > -1) { // só porque o replace não é global.
        output = output.replace(input, "");
    }
    return output;
}
```

Note que esse método não altera a string, mas retorna uma nova.

E pra testar, após executar o código acima, você pode fazer no console:

```
"abcde".remover("c");
```